# Trying to understand how to find structs in my project and packages

Tags: go

In my main.go I am trying to reference a struct, I'm getting a error:

> undefined: UserService

/main.go with package main

```
userService := &UserService{}
```

/services/user_service.go with package main

```
type UserService struct {
  // ..
}
```

Why can't it find my struct?
Can I put my /services files in a different package?  If so, then how would I reference them in my main.go file?

Comment: How are you building and running the code? `go run main.go`? Or `go build`?

Comment: I am running it using ```go run main.go```

Comment: Start with [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)

Comment: It's `go build` not `go run`. go run is for helper scripts once you are confident with the language and the tooling.

Answer (score 1):

> *I am running it using `go run main.go`.*

That's a problem. `go run main.go` will only build `main.go`. For a project that is more than one file, use `go build`. It will then find your source files and build them. But that isn't going to work either because you're not following the Go conventions for source layout.

The `go` tool enforces a very particular way of structuring your project. You can read about this in [How To Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html). In general, the source code tree is flat. `go build` is simply not finding `services/user_service.go`. You can see this with `go build -x`.

```
$ tree
.
├── main.go
└── service
    └── user_service.go

1 directory, 2 files

$ go build -x
WORK=/var/folders/0b/7xp2lxbd7yl0tcpms06fr3d40000gn/T/go-build148902279
mkdir -p $WORK/soq/_obj/
mkdir -p $WORK/soq/_obj/exe/
cd /Users/schwern/go/src/soq
/opt/local/lib/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/compile -o $WORK/soq.a -trimpath $WORK -goversion go1.9.3 -p main -complete -buildid 08f76ca23c0110836288d4a2c698c2692588f909 -D _/Users/schwern/go/src/soq -I $WORK -pack ./main.go
# soq
./main.go:8:21: undefined: UserService
```

Note that `compile` is only working on `main.go`.

The simple solution is to flatten your source tree.

```
$ tree
.
├── main.go
└── user_service.go

0 directories, 2 files

$ go build -x
WORK=/var/folders/0b/7xp2lxbd7yl0tcpms06fr3d40000gn/T/go-build117658131
mkdir -p $WORK/soq/_obj/
mkdir -p $WORK/soq/_obj/exe/
cd /Users/schwern/go/src/soq
/opt/local/lib/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/compile -o $WORK/soq.a -trimpath $WORK -goversion go1.9.3 -p main -complete -buildid 8dfd03a3d0d09267ebc5ff9d1b8dd630d7465e9c -D _/Users/schwern/go/src/soq -I $WORK -pack ./main.go ./user_service.go
cd .
/opt/local/lib/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/link -o $WORK/soq/_obj/exe/a.out -L $WORK -extld=/usr/bin/clang -buildmode=exe -buildid=8dfd03a3d0d09267ebc5ff9d1b8dd630d7465e9c $WORK/soq.a
mv $WORK/soq/_obj/exe/a.out soq
```

And now it works fine.

---

You might be thinking "*but what if I want to do more complicated things?*"

You *could* write your own build tool that walked sub-directories to find all the Go files and feed them to `go build`. But that goes against the nature of Go, and you'll find yourself having to subvert more and more tools as time goes on.

Go is deliberately designed to discourage complexity. Large source trees with subdirectories encourage complexity and allow entangled subsystems, so the `go` tool does not help you with them. (The Go language does not care about your file structure, just the `go` build tool).

Instead, the Go way to deal with this is to split your `services` off into a new package. Develop it with clear boundaries, and without the temptation to couple it to other systems, and `import` it into your main package.

Comment: so how does the golang revel framework work the?  https://revel.github.io/manual/organization.html   thanks!

Comment: @Blankman They appear to be using their own tool to build their apps, not the `go` tool. You build the example "booking" app not with `go build` but with `revel run github.com/revel/examples/booking`. You'll want to use a pre-existing framework and their tools. Note that [the actual `revel` command](https://github.com/revel/cmd/tree/master/revel) uses the flat layout because it must be buildable with `go get`.